# How to upload image which is already in <img src> in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I have a existing image which is display in `<img ng-src=''>` and I want to upload(post together with my other json object) it when I click the submit button. The image is existing so I don't need to used `<input type ="file">`. But the code I have is not working. Can anyone help me how to achieve this. Thank u very much.

[plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/iES8EnEMnqWr6A8gQP3k?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while, however I just want to show how I implemented the similar functionality

### Demo

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/sud0WL?p=preview)

**Action plan**:

- Convert `img/URL` to `Base64` format.
- add the `Base64` data as a property to `scope`.

**Steps taken**:

- Created a factory to convert URL to `Base64` using canvas and promises.
- Modified `fileInput` directive such that on image `load` event, it will convert `img` to `Base64` and assign `imgData` property on `scope`.
- Using the `imgData` property, append the `Base64` encoded string to `formData`

### Directive

```
link: function(scope, ele, attrs) {
  ele.bind('load', function(e) {
    var imgSrc = e.target.src;
    urlToBase64.getData(imgSrc).then(function(data) {
      scope.imgData = data;
    });
    scope.$apply();
  });
}
```

### Factory

```
myApp.factory('urlToBase64', ['$q', function($q) {

  var obj = {};
  // function to convert URL to Base64 representation
  function URLtoBase64(url, callback) {
    var defer = $q.defer();

    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      canvas.height = this.height;
      canvas.width = this.width;
      ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
      try {
        defer.resolve(canvas.toDataURL());
      } catch (e) {
        defer.reject(e);
      }
      canvas = null;
    };
    img.src = url;

    return defer.promise;
  }

  obj.getData = URLtoBase64;
  return obj;
}]);
```

### Controller

```
var fd = new FormData();
// imgData is coming from fileInput directive
fd.append('file', $scope.imgData);
fd.append('formdata', JSON.stringify($scope.dataform));
var reqObject = {
  url: 'admin/managecuisineAdd',
  method: 'POST',
  data: fd,
  transformRequest: angular.identity,
  headers: {
    'Content-type': undefined
  }
};
$http(reqObject).then(function(data) {
  $scope.status = data;
  $scope.itemlist.push(data)
  $scope.message = "New Dish Added Successfully"
});
```